# Monaco editor change custom types behaviour

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I have discovered how to add custom completions to custom declared classes for the Monaco editor. Like below:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib([
'declare class Facts {',
'    /**',
'     * Returns the next fact',
'     */',
'    static next():string',
'}',
].join('\n'), 'filename/facts.d.ts');
```

But the problem I have now is that the new `Facts` type also shows inherited methods and properties like `prototype`:

[image]
Is there a way to disable default class/type behaviour and only show the custom methods declared?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your definition from a class to an object. Then it will only display the properties you define on it.

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib([
'declare const Facts = {',
'    /**',
'     * Returns the next fact',
'     */',
'    static next():string',
'}',
].join('\n'), 'filename/facts.d.ts');
```